# How to create an array from an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Student> alist = new ArrayList();
// object type is student
//arraylist contains student objects        
Student[] arr= new Student[un.size()];

for(int i = 0; i <= alist .size(); i++){
    them[i] = arr.get(i);
}
```

What I want to do is to create an array of students  without getting the array out of bounds exception.

Comment: i think  err is you have un object for size . use alist.size(). plus api method is there see Stendika's answer

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are *zero-based* in Java (and most languages). If you have an array of size `N`, the indexes will be from [0, N-1] (Total size of `N`).

```
i <= alist .size()
```

should be

```
i < alist .size()
   ↑
 No "="
```

Why don't you simply use [`toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29)?

Comment: @ZouZou Indeed. Thanks, fixed the link :)

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. Your for loop condition says to loop as long as `i` is less than or equal to `alist.size()`. If you do that, you'll always run one over.

For example, if you only have one item in `alist`, your size will be 1, but you really only want to loop until 0.

Change this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= alist.size()  ; i++)
```

To this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <  alist.size()  ; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

All you really need is to say is `them = alist.toArray(new Student[them.length])`. This will simply copy the data over.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Student> alist = new ArrayList();
// object type is student
//arraylist contains student objects        
Student[] arr= new Student[un.size()];
alist.toArray(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also, All above ans are correct but this is simple and easy

```
String[] arr = alist.toArray(new Student[un.size()]);
```

**[list.toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)** *`return an array containing all of the elements in this collection`*